# Origin of ratchasap/ราชาศัพท์ phenomenon in Thai and/or Tai-kadai languages

Tags: historical-linguistics, etymology, sanskrit, thai, lao

I am attempting to trace the origin of "rachasap" (Thai: ราชาศัพท์; Lao: ລາດຊະຊັບ).

**What is "rachasap"?**

Rachasap is an entire body of words that are used with deity, royalty, or monks.  For example, when speaking of a body part for one of these entities, rachasap is used in place of the normal word; e.g. "พระเนตร/pra-ned" for "eye" in place of "ตา/dta" as normal.  The "พระ/pra" prefix is common in rachasap, as is the use of a special helping verb before verbs (which may also be in rachasap form themselves, i.e. a completely different word than the normal verb).  Some might call rachasap "royal language."

Specifically, I am interested in knowing how deeply rachasap may be connected to Buddhism, and why or how rachasap began in the first place.  Tai-kadai languages have been heavily influenced by Pali and Sanskrit, both languages closely related to Buddhism.  But I do not know Pali or Sanskrit, and am not aware of any good etymological sources for these.

I am seeking recommendations on source materials for the etymology or history of rachasap, and/or similar information about it.

Comment: are you interested in the etymologies of this alternative lexicon, or the origin of this distinct register? I'll also note that the Tai-Kadai/Kra-Dai languages do _not_ have roots in Pali or Sanskrit, but are an independent language family unrelated to Indo-European. Many Tai-Kadai/Kra-Dai languages have borrowed a significant amount of vocabulary fro Pali and Sanskrit, but that is a very different thing

Comment: Edited the title as there's a close-vote for "contextless etymology" while this question is about the phenomenon itself, not about the term.

Comment: @Tristan It is common knowledge within Thailand and Laos that the language has roots in Pali and Sanskrit.  [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_language) agrees: "Thai is the most spoken of over 60 languages of Thailand by both number of native and overall speakers. Over half of its vocabulary is derived from or borrowed from Pali, Sanskrit, Mon[5] and Old Khmer." Note the "derived from".  That said, my question seeks to know why there is ratchasap in these languages, so if the answer comes back that it arose from other than Pali or Sanskrit, fine.  I simply suspect those languages.

Comment: @Biblasia "common knowledge" is frequently incorrect, or a misunderstanding of fact. Raw percentages of vocabulary are not a good metric for descent, and statements that a language "derives from" another are generally interpreted as referring to genetic descent, not lexical proximity. From a linguistic perspective, the claim that Tai-Kadai/Kra-Dai languages "have roots in Pali and Sanskrit" is simply incorrect. As stated in my original comment the correct statement is that they have borrowed a lot of vocabulary from Pali and Sanskrit

Comment: To add to @Tristan’s comment, note that the Wikipedia quote (correctly) says that over half of its _vocabulary_ (i.e., individual words) is derived or borrowed from Pali, Sanskrit, Mon and Khmer – not that the _language itself_ is derived from any of those. More than half of the vocabulary of English is derived or borrowed from Latin or its Romance descendants (primarily French), but that does not mean English has French/Romance/Latin roots or is derived from it: English has _Germanic_ roots and is derived from Proto-Germanic, via various intermediate stages.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet I'm really not interested in a discussion of _roots_ of anything other than the _ratchasap_.  I would prize learning where this has come from...hence the question.

Comment: I’ve edited the question to avoid further derailment on this relatively minor tangent.

Comment: fyi, the wikipedia page for Thai includes the (unsourced, so no idea how reliable it is) statement that "Royal Thai (ราชาศัพท์, racha sap): influenced by Khmer, this is used when addressing members of the royal family or describing their activities. (See Monarchy of Thailand § Rachasap.)" (unfortunately the linked page includes no further discussion on the origins). The talk page also has the statement "Royal language usually comes from Khmer language so when you call anythings and any activities aboult royals. you must use a royal word" from GoodGuy

Comment: as I have no way to judge the accuracy of these statements (not knowing Thai or Khmer, or the relevant descriptions), I can't really chase this claim up to turn it into a proper answer, but if you do know the languages in question, you can see for yourself. I'd assume this arose during the Khmer Empire when Khmer-speakers dominated SE Asia for ~600 years

Comment: @Tristan I can understand only about 10% of Khmer, as it is that much different from Thai.  It is, perhaps, akin to Mandarin versus Cantonese--the latter of which is said to be about 90% different from Mandarin, even though both are "Chinese."  The statement about "royal language" is otherwise inaccurate in that it is not limited to usage with the monarchy, for it also applies to any deity and to the monks (though many may ignore the rules except when addressing the monarchy in person). I'd like better documentation than this "Khmer", as it appears almost like hearsay. But thanks for the lead.

Comment: Khmer & Thai are much more distantly related than Mandarin & Cantonese. Thai is Tai-Kadai/Kra-Dai whilst Khmer is Austroasiatic. There is promising research on a connection between these two families but no relationship has yet been proven. Otoh Mandarin and Chinese are both Sinitic languages descended from Middle Chinese within the broader Sino-Tibetan family. Regardless, the Wikipedia page describes the language used to talk to/about monks as "Religious Thai" which it states is heavily influenced by Sanskrit and Pali. Again I don't know how accurate it is to split these two higher registers

Comment: @Tristan It appears that the [Khmer link](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Khmer_language) to the royal language is inferred from the fact that Khmer has "a system of registers in which the speaker must always be conscious of the social status of the person spoken to."  Apparently, this language is more strongly typed than its neighbors, having multiple levels of status-oriented language.  Thai has three or at most four levels, but it seems Khmer has nearly twice this, based on the example chart.  I would like to see more morphological evidence to support this link...looking into this further.

Answer (score 4):

**ราชาศัพท์** *raa-chaa-sàp* itself is a Pali-derived word, ราชา *raa-chaa* (राज *rājā* "king, monarch") + ศัพท์ *sàp* (originally from Sanskrit शब्द *śabda* "word"); hence, "Royal Language". However, it is commonly interpreted in modern Thai culture as referring to the whole [honorific system of modern Thai](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thai_honorifics), although strictly speaking it refers to *royal honorifics*, both speaking to and speaking about the royal family.

Cultural borrowings between Thai and Khmer are extremely well known, with two-way interchange connected to the history of the peoples around the Chao Phraya River Valley, and especially when it came to [royal culture](http://sealang.net/sala/archives/pdf8/wilaiwan2004khmero.pdf). As one scholar put it:

> For centuries, Khmer and Thai existed in veritable symbiosis.

Putting this into a greater liturgical context of Theravada Buddhism, with the liturgical language being Sanskrit and Pali, we see an extra layer of honorificity and formality in the Thai language, what can be called *clerical honorifics*.

Interestingly, old Tai Lü (Tai Lue) manuscripts (written in Tai Tham script) [do *not* show evidence of royal honorifics](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Chronicles_of_Chiang_Khaeng/pAgWAQAAMAAJ), even though they date from a similar period with the Sukhothai Thai language manuscripts from the 13th century CE. Rather, we see the rise of ราชาศัพท์ *raa-chaa-sàp*, [in the early Ayutthaya era](https://books.google.co.uk/books?newbks=1&newbks_redir=0&redir_esc=y&id=5aAsEAAAQBAJ) (from the Gregorian Year 1351 onwards) as the "court language", and was officially enshrined in the [Law of the Civil Hierarchy](http://sealang.net/sala/archives/pdf8/wilaiwan2004khmero.pdf) by King Baromtrailokanat.

However, indications that there was a "court language" even in the time of the Sukhothai, as seems to be evident in the writings of Maha Thammaracha I as [Li Thai](https://theses.hal.science/tel-01869059/document). On the other hand, there is no evidence of it in the inscriptions of Ramkhamhaeng.

The honorific systems in Thai, Khmer, Tibetan and also Javanese are principally based on [lexical substitution](https://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/abs/10.1002/9781118371008.ch17); the substitutions here are much more extensive in the vocabulary than the few substitutions in the primarily morphological honorific systems in e.g. Japanese and Korean. Different items of vocabulary are used to refer to various registers, and often whole turns of phrase are reworded to be more appropriate to the sociolinguistic register.

E.g. for "to sleep":

- นอน *nɔɔn* (inherited from Proto-Tai)
- จำวัด *jam-wát* (Khmer-based compound, lit. "confine in a temple")
- ผทม/บรรทม/ประทม *pà-tom/ban-tom/bprà-tom* (from Old Khmer; in modern Khmer ផ្ *phtum* is also part of "royal language")

Comment: +1 Thank you.  This has provided links to some good sources.  I do wish, however, that I had clearer answers on my principal question: _"Specifically, I am interested in knowing how deeply rachasap may be connected to Buddhism, and **why** or how rachasap began in the first place."_  It appears from materials linked in your answer that rachasap began with a king (U-thong --> Ramathibodi) wanting to promote himself as god.